# String resource and decimal format

Tags: android, android-resources, decimalformat

I know I can format a number to a String with decimal separators like:

```
NumberFormat.getInstance().format(1000)
```

and receive the String `1,000`.

How can I apply this to formated Strings from `strings.xml` resources?

Example:

```
 <string name="number_of_results">%1$d results</string>
```

Calling

```
getString(R.string.number_of_results, 1000)
```

will return `1000 results`. How can I get `1,000 results`?

Answer (score 4):

Android string resources are not that smart. If you need sophisticated formatting you should do it yourself, and then insert it as a string:

```
<string name="number_of_results">%1$s results</string>
```

And then

```
getString(R.string.number_of_results, NumberFormat.getInstance().format(1000));
```

The formatting libraries usually provide you interface for the locale setup, so your numbers will be properly localized, no worries here.